# How to make a space between images in React Native Project?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

Now I am creating a mobile app with React Native and Expo.

I set ScrollView and View, Image, Text inside ScrollView.
I would like to make some space between each images but I couldn't.

Of course I tried to use Padding and Margin in styleSheet but these are not working.

This is my code.

```
  renderShopList() {
    return shopLists.map((value, index) => {
     return (
      <View
       key={index}
       style={styles.shopListBox}
      >
       <Image
        source={value.image}
        style={styles.shopListImage}
      />
       <View style={styles.shopListTextBox}>
        <Text style={styles.shopListText}>
          {value.genre}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
   );
 });
}
```

This is my StyleSheet below.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
  flex: 0.2,
 },
 shopListBox: {
  width: 140,
  height: 105,
  marginTop: '8%',
 },
 shopListImage: {
  width: 140,
  height: 105,
  marginLeft: '12%',
  borderRadius: 4,
 },
 shopListTextBox: {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: '26%',
  left: '12%',
  width: 140,
  paddingTop: '2%',
  paddingBottom: '2%',
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(111,111,111,0.8)',
 },
 shopListText: {
  fontSize: 25,
  fontWeight: '900',
  color: '#fff',
  paddingLeft: '28%',
 },
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doing margins by percent won't work for direct children inside a scrollView because the it grows, if you are trying to do relative sizing for multiple screen sizes do something like this [react-native-size-matters](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-size-matters)